# Episode notes for podcast episode 458 links the wrong answer for the Lifeboat badge

Tags: bug, blog, podcast

The podcast [episode notes](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/exploring-the-interesting-and-strange-results-from-our-2022-developer-survey) (and [the blog post containing them](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/01/exploring-the-interesting-and-strange-results-from-our-2022-developer-survey-ep-458/)) say:

> Today’s [Lifeboat badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat) goes to user [Jarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040668/jarzon) for their answer to [Make a hidden field required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917016/make-a-hidden-field-required/65356856#65356856).

[Jarzon's answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917245/208273) is indeed quite good!  It's got a runnable Stack Snippet and everything.

So it's a pity that the episode notes link the *other* answer on that question, which should probably have been a comment under Jarzon's answer.

...also there's no transcript, but I assume that's a WIP?  Not sure if those come out at the same time as the podcast.

Comment: Very true, if an answer deserves mention it also deserves the right link :P