# Episode 464 blog post links the wrong post for the Lifeboat badge shoutout

Tags: bug, blog, podcast

The podcast episode notes in the blog post, [Code completion isn’t magic; it just feels that way](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/19/code-completion-isnt-magic-it-just-feels-that-way-ep-464/), links the question, instead of the answer, for the Lifeboat badge shoutout:

> The [Lifeboat badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat) shoutout is back. Today’s badge goes to user [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605744/tomasz-nurkiewicz) for their answer to [Best performance for string-to-Boolean conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044721/best-performance-for-string-to-boolean-conversion).

In general, since all Lifeboat badge shoutouts link to the answer rather than the question, the above link should instead lead to Tomasz Nurkiewicz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044721/best-performance-for-string-to-boolean-conversion/12044775#12044775).

---

Related post: [Episode notes for podcast episode 458 links the wrong answer for the Lifeboat badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379995/episode-notes-for-podcast-episode-458-links-the-wrong-answer-for-the-lifeboat-ba) (still not fixed).